# How to transfer a Pokémon from cartridge to ROM?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum, pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon, homebrew

I have a Gible I want to put in Pokémon Platinum. The problem is that the Gible is on a Pokémon Ultra Moon cartridge and I have no clue how to bring a Pokémon from a cartridge to a ROM. I cannot find a video on how to do it, please help.

(I’m using a homebrew 2dsxl with Twilight menu with Pokémon chest and PKSM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is another one.
Pokemon *Ultra Moon* is **not compatible** with *Platinum*, you can't transfer Pokemon backwards with different generations.

As you can see from this schema, it's unidirectional:
[image]

<sub>([Source](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/pokemon-go-home-connectivity-transfer-creatures-sword-and-shield-nintendo-switch-2324804))</sub>

You may have to generate it on Platinum ROM using cheats.